# Get file names from dynamically changing folder structure (vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder which contains four further folders.

- 20180304
- 20180412
- 20180622
- 20170702

I want to see when get the searched file leatest, so I need to find the file in these folders and the connected folder names dinamically. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: This question has been answered more than 10 times I think. Do some research before you ask ([ask]). And if you still have a question, show what you researched so far and what you have tried by showing your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a For Each loop once you provide the root folder.

### Example:

> Create an instance of the FileSystemObject

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

> Get the folder object

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Temp")
```

> loops through each folder in the directory

```
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    **Handle Code Goes Here**
Next objSubFolder
```

So now you have each subfolder of the root folder you provided (C:\Temp) in this case, you can do something like this to get information:

```
String1 = objSubFolder.Path 
String 2 = objSubFolder.Name
```